# $('div:first').is(':first') returns false, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This looks like a bug, but I'm not sure.

As far as I know, jQuerys `.is()` method will just check if the selector string matches the element you call it on (if you pass in a selector string ofc...)

If you full qualify the statement into

```
$('div:first').is('div:first')
```

it will correctly return `true`, but.. here comes the facepalm for me:

```
$('div:last').is(':last')
```

will again, correctly return `true`.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/d6UGw/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with your markup.

---

`div:last` means the last `div` in your markup.

`:last` means the last `element` in your markup.

It's probably returning true because your last element is a div.

---

`div:first` means the first div in your markup.

`:first` always returns the `<html>` element, as in a valid HTML doc, it's your first element.

So `$('div:first').is(':first')` should never return true in a valid HTML doc.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Added more info.

Comment: if there is no html tag in your html, it will be created implicitly. It is not a required tag in valid html. `<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>hello</title>
<body><div>world</div>` is valid html document

Comment: @Esailija A valid *HTML5* document, I don't think previous (e.g. 4.01 strict/transitional) were as lenient ..

Comment: @pst you just need to change the doctype for those. `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><title>hello</title> <body><div>world</div>` is valid html 4.01 strict. And, OP yes it's not valid xhtml I never claimed so. I think you will find valid xhtml hard to do without using javascript to insert some attributes and you have to wonder at that point if it's even worth it.